# Why does this Ada program not throw a constraint error?

Tags: ada

I expected the following code to throw a constraint error on compilation, however it didn't. It also does not throw a runtime error on the c2 assignment. Edit: Running the compiler with -gnata solves the compilation warning issue, but does not solve the lack-of runtime error issue. It is compiled using GNAT FSF with no optimizations, just: gnatmake main Edit: gnatmake -gnata main

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
    subtype cat is Integer with Dynamic_Predicate => cat in 1 .. 9;

    c1 : cat;
    c2 : cat;
begin
    c1 := 5;
    c2 := 99;
end Main;
```

I thought that the Dynamic_Predicate line would essentially be equivalent to the following :

```
subtype cat is Integer range 1 .. 9;
```

Comment: @PaulCrovella The question that you are quoting answers the lack-of compilation error issue, but does not address why a runtime error is not produced when the program is actually executed.

Comment: You could make the predicate static.  The expression is one of those allowed for static predicates.

Comment: Which FSF GCC are you using?

Comment: @SimonWright I am using TDM-GCC-64, which is gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1). This is through the git bash terminal on Windows 10 pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I build your example, I get a compile-time warning, and a run-time error:

```
$ gnatmake -gnata -gnato -fstack-check -gnat12 -gnatyO -gnatv -gnati1 -gnatf -gnatn -m -j0 main.adb
gcc-6 -c -gnata -gnato -fstack-check -gnat12 -gnatyO -gnatv -gnati1 -gnatf -gnatn main.adb

GNAT 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright 1992-2016, Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Compiling: main.adb
Source file time stamp: 2018-08-02 06:08:55
Compiled at: 2018-08-02 08:11:00

    10.     c2 := 99;
                  |
        >>> warning: expression fails predicate check on "cat"

 11 lines: No errors, 1 warning
gnatbind-6 -x main.ali
gnatlink-6 main.ali -fstack-check
$ ./main

raised SYSTEM.ASSERTIONS.ASSERT_FAILURE : Dynamic_Predicate failed at main.adb:10
$
```

I quess your problem is that the default assertion policy in GCC/GNAT is `Ignore`.  I use the flag `-gnata` to override that.

Notice that the compiler only gives you a warning.  That's because the program is completely legal, even if it will raise an exception at run-time.  (This is the same, no matter if you use `range`, `Static_Predicate` or `Dynamic_Predicate` to specify the subset.)